# Insert data with data type in laravel?

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I am using laravel with mongodb, This is my update query

```
 $user = User::where('_id', '=', $row)
                 ->update(['userid' => $userid,
                'username' => $username,
                'email' => $emailid,
                'mobileno' => $mobile,
                'manager_mail' => $manager_mail,
                'roleid' => $role]);
```

While inserting role id is inserted as a string, how can i insert as a integer? please help

Comment: working...thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know `$roleid` will always be a numeric value, you can use `intval` in php when passing `$roleid`.

E.g. `intval($role)`

Read about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php